# CakePHP: How can i stop inserting/adding html tag during commenting of a post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is the form for comment:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('url'=>array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' =>'add', $listposts['Post']['id']) ) );

echo $this->Form->input('post_id',array('type'=>'hidden','style'=>'width:30%','value'=>$listposts['Post']['id']));  
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('style'=>'width:30%'));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('style'=>'width:30%'));   
echo $this->Form->input('body',array('rows'=>'5'));

echo $this->Form->end('Comment');
```

The comment.php model =>

```
var $useTable='comments';
var $belongsTo = array('Post');


var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Name.'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Email.'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Enter Body.'
    )
);
```

}

But during commenting someone can type in any textbox of the comment form like this =>

```
<script>
    alert("Hello world");
</script>
```

Then this alert will be displayed during the page load.
How can i stop inserting this html tags in database ?
How can i check this html block ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this: *sanitizing* or *escaping* the string. Sanitizing means you strip all unwanted content out. Escaping means you "disable" any *special characters* in the string. You should **always** escape user-supplied content when outputting it:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($comment['body']);
```

Optionally you *may* want to sanitize the string, but that can be tricky. Look into [Cake's `Sanitize` class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitization). [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) is also apropos.

Comment: Should i remove tags before saving data from form fields ? Or should i use strip_tags() before echoing strings ?

Comment: @guru Depends. I prefer to store any input in its original form and alter it during output only. You will never get the original back if you discard information immediately. It's really up to you and your priorities though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$str = "<script>alert('Hello world');</script>";

echo "strip_tags = " . strip_tags($str);
echo "htmlspecialchars = " . htmlspecialchars($str);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/iuMfn)

Comment: Should i remove tags before saving data from form fields ? Or should i use strip_tags() before echoing strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php